# Implement a button on the Shopify Debut theme carousel

Tags: ruby, shopify, liquid

Is there a way to implement a button onto the slider on the Debut theme? I just want it to route to a particular page. Here is the code:

```
<div data-section-id="{{ section.id }}" data-section-type="slideshow-section">

  {% if section.blocks.size > 0 %}
    <div class="slideshow-wrapper">
      <button type="button" class="visually-hidden slideshow__pause" data-id="{{ section.id }}" aria-live="polite">
        <span class="slideshow__pause-stop">
          {% include 'icon-pause' %}
          <span class="icon__fallback-text">{{ 'sections.slideshow.pause_slideshow' | t }}</span>
        </span>
        <span class="slideshow__pause-play">
          {% include 'icon-play' %}
          <span class="icon__fallback-text">{{ 'sections.slideshow.play_slideshow' | t }}</span>
        </span>
      </button>

      <div class="slideshow slideshow--{{ section.settings.slideshow_height }}" id="Slideshow-{{ section.id }}" data-autoplay="{{ section.settings.autoplay }}" data-speed="{{ section.settings.autoplay_speed }}">
        {% for block in section.blocks %}
          {%- assign is_background_video = false -%}
          {% if block.type == 'video' %}
            {% if block.settings.video_type == 'background' or block.settings.video_type =='background-chrome' %}
              {%- assign is_background_video = true -%}
            {% endif %}
          {% endif %}

          <div class="slideshow__slide slideshow__slide--{{ block.id }}{% if is_background_video %} slideshow__slide--background-video{% endif %}" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
            {% if block.settings.link != blank %}
              <a href="{{ block.settings.link }}" class="slideshow__link">
            {% endif %}

            {% if block.type == 'video' %}
              {% if block.settings.video_url != blank %}
                <div class="video-loader"></div>
              {% endif %}
              {% unless block.settings.video_type == 'background' %}
                <button type="button" class="text-link slideshow__video-control slideshow__video-control--close" data-controls="SlideshowVideo-{{ block.id }}">
                  {% include 'icon-close' %}
                  <span class="icon__fallback-text">{{ 'sections.slideshow.close_video' | t }}</span>
                </button>
              {% endunless %}
              {% if block.settings.video_url != blank %}
                <div id="SlideshowVideo-{{ block.id }}" class="slideshow__video {% if is_background_video %}slideshow__video--background{% endif %} slideshow__video--{{ block.settings.video_type }}"
                  data-id="{{ block.settings.video_url.id }}"
                  data-type="{{ block.settings.video_type }}"
                  data-slideshow="Slideshow-{{ section.id }}"></div>
              {% endif %}
            {% endif %}

            {% if block.settings.image == blank %}
              <div class="slideshow__image js">
                <div class="placeholder-background">
                  {% capture current %}{% cycle 1, 2 %}{% endcapture %}
                  {{ 'lifestyle-' | append: current | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
                </div>
              </div>
            {% else %}
              <div class="slideshow__image box ratio-container lazyload{% unless forloop.first == true %} lazypreload{% endunless %} js"
                   data-bgset="{% include 'bgset', image: block.settings.image %}"
                   data-sizes="auto"
                   data-parent-fit="cover"
                   style="background-position: {{ block.settings.alignment }};{% if forloop.first == true %} background-image: url('{{ block.settings.image | img_url: '300x300' }});{% endif %}">
              </div>
            {% endif %}

            <noscript>
              <div class="slideshow__image"{% if block.settings.image %} style="background-image: url('{{ block.settings.image | img_url: '2048x' }}'); background-position: {{ block.settings.alignment }};"{% endif %}>
                {% if block.settings.image == blank %}
                  <div class="placeholder-background">
                    {% capture current %}{% cycle 1, 2 %}{% endcapture %}
                    {{ 'lifestyle-' | append: current | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
                  </div>
                {% endif %}
              </div>
            </noscript>
            <div class="slideshow__text-wrap{% if block.settings.title != blank or block.settings.subheading != blank %} slideshow__overlay{% endif %}">
              <div class="slideshow__text-content">
                <div class="page-width">
                  {% unless block.settings.title == blank %}
                    <h2 class="h1 mega-title slideshow__title{% if settings.link != blank %} slideshow__title--has-link{% endif %}{% if section.settings.text_size == 'large' %} mega-title--large{% endif %}">
                      {{ block.settings.title | escape }}
                    </h2>
                  {% endunless %}
                  {% unless block.settings.subheading == blank %}
                    <span class="mega-subtitle slideshow__subtitle{% if section.settings.text_size == 'large' %} mega-subtitle--large{% endif %}">
                      {{ block.settings.subheading | escape }}
                    </span>
                  {% endunless %}
                  {% if block.type == 'video' %}
                    {% unless block.settings.video_type == 'background' %}
                      <div class="slideshow__video-control--play-wrapper{% if block.settings.title != blank or block.settings.subheading != blank %} slideshow__video-control--play-wrapper--push{% endif %}">
                        <button type="button" class="text-link slideshow__video-control slideshow__video-control--play" data-controls="SlideshowVideo-{{ block.id }}">
                          {% include 'icon-play-video' %}
                          <span class="icon__fallback-text">{{ 'sections.slideshow.play_video' | t }}</span>
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    {% endunless %}
                  {% endif %}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            {% if block.settings.link != blank %}
              </a>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endif %}

  {% if section.blocks.size == 0 %}
    <div class="placeholder-noblocks">
      {{ 'homepage.onboarding.no_content' | t }}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: Yep there is a way, just add another text or url field in the section block schema and add the html markup for the button.

Comment: Can you please show me where to find this and the markup should look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Replace your code with this code in slideshow.liquid:

```
<div data-section-id="{{ section.id }}" data-section-type="slideshow-section">
    {% if section.blocks.size > 0 %}
<div class="slideshow-wrapper">
  <button type="button" class="visually-hidden slideshow__pause" data-id="{{ section.id }}" aria-live="polite">
    <span class="slideshow__pause-stop">
      {% include 'icon-pause' %}
      <span class="icon__fallback-text">{{ 'sections.slideshow.pause_slideshow' | t }}</span>
    </span>
    <span class="slideshow__pause-play">
      {% include 'icon-play' %}
      <span class="icon__fallback-text">{{ 'sections.slideshow.play_slideshow' | t }}</span>
    </span>
  </button>

  <div class="slideshow slideshow--{{ section.settings.slideshow_height }}" id="Slideshow-{{ section.id }}" data-autoplay="{{ section.settings.autoplay }}" data-speed="{{ section.settings.autoplay_speed }}">
    {% for block in section.blocks %}
      {%- assign is_background_video = false -%}
      {% if block.type == 'video' %}
        {% if block.settings.video_type == 'background' or block.settings.video_type =='background-chrome' %}
          {%- assign is_background_video = true -%}
        {% endif %}
      {% endif %}

      <div class="slideshow__slide slideshow__slide--{{ block.id }}{% if is_background_video %} slideshow__slide--background-video{% endif %}" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
        {% if block.settings.link != blank %}
          <a href="{{ block.settings.link }}" class="slideshow__link">
        {% endif %}

        {% if block.type == 'video' %}
          {% if block.settings.video_url != blank %}
            <div class="video-loader"></div>
          {% endif %}
          {% unless block.settings.video_type == 'background' %}
            <button type="button" class="text-link slideshow__video-control slideshow__video-control--close" data-controls="SlideshowVideo-{{ block.id }}">
              {% include 'icon-close' %}
              <span class="icon__fallback-text">{{ 'sections.slideshow.close_video' | t }}</span>
            </button>
          {% endunless %}
          {% if block.settings.video_url != blank %}
            <div id="SlideshowVideo-{{ block.id }}" class="slideshow__video {% if is_background_video %}slideshow__video--background{% endif %} slideshow__video--{{ block.settings.video_type }}"
              data-id="{{ block.settings.video_url.id }}"
              data-type="{{ block.settings.video_type }}"
              data-slideshow="Slideshow-{{ section.id }}"></div>
          {% endif %}
        {% endif %}

        {% if block.settings.image == blank %}
          <div class="slideshow__image js">
            <div class="placeholder-background">
              {% capture current %}{% cycle 1, 2 %}{% endcapture %}
              {{ 'lifestyle-' | append: current | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
            </div>
          </div>
        {% else %}
          <div class="slideshow__image box ratio-container lazyload{% unless forloop.first == true %} lazypreload{% endunless %} js"
               data-bgset="{% include 'bgset', image: block.settings.image %}"
               data-sizes="auto"
               data-parent-fit="cover"
               style="background-position: {{ block.settings.alignment }};{% if forloop.first == true %} background-image: url('{{ block.settings.image | img_url: '300x300' }});{% endif %}">
          </div>
        {% endif %}

        <noscript>
          <div class="slideshow__image"{% if block.settings.image %} style="background-image: url('{{ block.settings.image | img_url: '2048x' }}'); background-position: {{ block.settings.alignment }};"{% endif %}>
            {% if block.settings.image == blank %}
              <div class="placeholder-background">
                {% capture current %}{% cycle 1, 2 %}{% endcapture %}
                {{ 'lifestyle-' | append: current | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
              </div>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        </noscript>
        <div class="slideshow__text-wrap{% if block.settings.title != blank or block.settings.subheading != blank %} slideshow__overlay{% endif %}">
          <div class="slideshow__text-content">
            <div class="page-width">
              {% unless block.settings.title == blank %}
                <h2 class="h1 mega-title slideshow__title{% if settings.link != blank %} slideshow__title--has-link{% endif %}{% if section.settings.text_size == 'large' %} mega-title--large{% endif %}">
                  {{ block.settings.title | escape }}
                </h2>
              {% endunless %}
              {% unless block.settings.subheading == blank %}
                <span class="mega-subtitle slideshow__subtitle{% if section.settings.text_size == 'large' %} mega-subtitle--large{% endif %}">
                  {{ block.settings.subheading | escape }}
                </span>
              {% endunless %}
              {% if block.type == 'video' %}
                {% unless block.settings.video_type == 'background' %}
                  <div class="slideshow__video-control--play-wrapper{% if block.settings.title != blank or block.settings.subheading != blank %} slideshow__video-control--play-wrapper--push{% endif %}">
                    <button type="button" class="text-link slideshow__video-control slideshow__video-control--play" data-controls="SlideshowVideo-{{ block.id }}">
                      {% include 'icon-play-video' %}
                      <span class="icon__fallback-text">{{ 'sections.slideshow.play_video' | t }}</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                {% endunless %}
              {% endif %}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        {% if block.settings.link != blank %}
          </a>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% if section.blocks.size == 0 %}
<div class="placeholder-noblocks">
  {{ 'homepage.onboarding.no_content' | t }}
</div>
{% endif %}
</div>
{% schema %}
{
"name": "Slideshow",
"class": "index-section index-section--flush",
"max_blocks": 4,
"settings": [
  {
    "type": "checkbox",
    "id": "autoplay",
    "label": "Auto-rotate slides",
    "default": true
  },
  {
    "type": "select",
    "id": "autoplay_speed",
    "label": "Change slides every",
    "options": [
      { "value": "5000", "label": "5 seconds" },
      { "value": "6000", "label": "6 seconds" },
      { "value": "7000", "label": "7 seconds" },
      { "value": "8000", "label": "8 seconds" },
      { "value": "9000", "label": "9 seconds" },
      { "value": "10000", "label": "10 seconds" }
    ],
    "default": "7000"
  },
  {
    "type": "select",
    "id": "slideshow_height",
    "label": "Section height",
    "default": "small",
    "options": [
      {
        "label": "Small",
        "value": "small"
      },
      {
        "label": "Medium",
        "value": "medium"
      },
      {
        "label": "Large",
        "value": "large"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "select",
    "id": "text_size",
    "label": "Text size",
    "default": "medium",
    "options": [
      {
        "label": "Medium",
        "value": "medium"
      },
      {
        "label": "Large",
        "value": "large"
      }
    ]
  }
],
"blocks": [
  {
    "type": "image",
    "name": "Image slide",
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "image_picker",
        "id": "image",
        "label": "Image"
      },
      {
        "type": "select",
        "id": "alignment",
        "label": "Image alignment",
        "default": "top",
        "options": [
          {
            "value": "top",
            "label": "Top"
          },
          {
            "value": "center",
            "label": "Middle"
          },
          {
            "value": "bottom",
            "label": "Bottom"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "title",
        "label": "Heading",
        "default": "Image slide"
      },
      {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "subheading",
        "label": "Subheading",
        "default": "Tell your brand's story through video and images"
      },
      {
        "type": "url",
        "id": "link",
        "label": "Slide link"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "video",
    "name": "Video slide",
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "video_url",
        "id": "video_url",
        "label": "Video link",
        "accept": ["youtube"],
        "default": "https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=_9VUPq3SxOc"
      },
      {
        "type": "select",
        "id": "video_type",
        "label": "Style",
        "options": [
          {
            "value": "chrome",
            "label": "Image with play button"
          },
          {
            "value": "background-chrome",
            "label": "Background video with play button"
          },
          {
            "value": "background",
            "label": "Background video"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "image_picker",
        "id": "image",
        "label": "Image",
        "info": "Fallback when autoplaying video is not supported on mobile devices"
      },
      {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "title",
        "label": "Heading",
        "default": "Video slide"
      },
      {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "subheading",
        "label": "Subheading",
        "default": "Tell your brand's story through video and images"
      }
    ]
  }
],
"presets": [{
  "name": "Slideshow",
  "category": "Image",
  "settings": {
    "autoplay": true,
    "autoplay_speed": "5000"
  },
  "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "image"
    },
    {
      "type": "image"
    }
    ]
   }]
  }
{% endschema %}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I tried this and it isn't working

Comment: May I know your website URL so that I can check why it's not working.